# Add directory to URL in Rails Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

For SEO purposes, I've appended a slug to an id, like so:

```
/browse/12885-evergreen-instrumental
```

by using this in my model:

```
  def to_param
    "#{id}-#{slug}" || id
  end
```

Ideally, I'd like to have the structure as so:

```
/browse/12885/evergreen-instrumental
```

I've tried several things via routes.rb to accomplish this, but to no avail yet.

Essentially, I'm trying to do this:

```
match "/browse/:id/:slug" => "tracks#show", as: :track
```

and than will want a redirect:

```
get '/browse/:track_id', to: redirect('/browse/%{track_id}/%{slug}')
```

Any ideas on how to get this to actually work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure, but what happens if you do:
`match "/browse/:id(/slug/:slug)"

Comment: you can handle it in your controller

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the [FriendlyId gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id). It does exactly what you are trying to do.